# can i fill pictures in a single row and keep aspect ratio simple with css grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

I want create a picture gallery like this:
1.pictures fill into a specify width container with its orginal aspect ratio
2.each row has its own height, which is automatic fit as more picture as possible
3.it must fluid

can it be achieved only by CSS grid layout?

skeleton codepen is here:
https://codepen.io/minzojian/pen/MWwopXP

```
<div class="grid">
<img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADTkhFsZ-A/1/thumbnail_large-2.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADGvpvY3HA/7/thumbnail_large.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADkaQ9LP_Y/1/thumbnail_large.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADR_1AI5vk/1/thumbnail_large-1.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADQ5O2kfiE/1/thumbnail_large-1.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADGyf4KZA8/4/thumbnail_large.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADT4-tuwa0/1/thumbnail_large-2.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://media-public.canva.com/MADSTxsB9aY/1/thumbnail_large-1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
.grid {
  width: 312px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set your grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows values ... then create grid-template-areas then assign what you want to go into which area.

grid-template-columns:  .....whatever
grid-tmeplate-rows: .....whatever

grid-template-areas: "A", "B", "C", "D";

## photo-b { grid-area: A 1; }

## photo-c { gird-area: B 1; }

etc..